# Selenium webdriver drag and drop not working (java)

Tags: java, selenium, drag-and-drop, webdriver

what I want to do is to drag a element in the left sidebar to the center area, as shown in the image. But not working, although no error message show up.
[image of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vawKf.png)
My code is:
`//drag and drop - not working
     WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='componentsSection']/div[1]/div[1]"));
     Thread.sleep(1000);
     WebElement target = driver.findElement(By.id("layoutSection"));
     Thread.sleep(1000);
     (new Actions(driver)).dragAndDrop(element, target).build().perform();`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can also try following:

Comment: try this my answer and replace your xpath properly inside `from` and `to` web-element.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try following approach:

```
(new Actions(driver)).clickAndHold(element).moveToElement(target).release(element).build().perform();
```